# How can I call a WebView from a ListView

Tags: android

I have the following XML:

```
<string-array name="bookmark_titles">
    <item>Google</item>
    <item>Android</item>
    <item>Offspot</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="bookmark_urls">
    <item>http://www.google.com</item>
    <item>http://www.android.com/</item>
    <item>http://www.offspot.com</item>
</string-array>
```

and this ListView in a separated file:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/favoritos_listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#ECECEC"
    android:dividerHeight="1sp" />
```

Wevbiew

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

This is how I implemente the ListView

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.bookmark_titles, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);
```

How can I call my WebView when I click on an Item in the ListView?

Comment: is your webview in same Activity or another activity?

Comment: It is another activy, because I have to click on item Google and open www.google.com. Right?

Comment: You can check my answer below pls accept if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Implement an [`OnItemClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) and set it to your `ListView` like so:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String url = getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bookmark_urls)[position];
    //opens the url in one of the Android Browsers.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    getContext().startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean override the onItemClick method?

Comment: Look at the implementation provided above. You'll need to create a new implementation of the `OnItemClickListener` interface and provide it to your `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of your WebView?

first thing you need a refernce to your webview.

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView)MyLayout.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

Then your listview needs a itemOnClick method which decides what to do when you click on a listview item

```
    //Show webview
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Show the webview
                mWebView.refreshDrawableState();
                mWebView.loadUrl("www.google.com");
            }
        });
```

if you need specific data from the item you clicked on you use the position variable to get at it - lv.getItemAtPosition(position)

Comment: Thank you, but where I put this code? Inside my "public class HomeActivity extends Activity"? I am getting this error: The type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)

Answer (score 0):

If in same Activity

```
WebView lWebView = (WebView)MyLayout.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    lWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);//you can use View.INVISIBLE also if you need to keep the space
    String[] lTestArray =  = getResources().getStringArray(R.array. bookmark_urls);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    lWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Show the webview
                    lWebView.loadUrl(lTestArray[position]);
                }
            });
```

**EDIT**  **Another Activity**
***ListView Class***

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    Intent intent=new Intent(this,YOURCLASS.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Link",lTestArray[position]);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

***WebView Class***

```
  Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    String link=bundle.getString("Link",null);
    if(!link.equals(null)){
    WebView lWebView = (WebView)MyLayout.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    lWebView.loadUrl(link);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with MyLayout at this code? I just put 
WebView lWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview). Algo I'm getting these erros: "Syntax error on token "setVisibility", Identifier expected after this token" and "Syntax error on token "setOnItemClickListener", = expected after this token"